# Images uploaded in wordpress have http rather that https in URL

Tags: wordpress, http, url, file-upload, https

When the chrome the developer tool on some of my web pages I get this warning

"The page at https://www.improvementskills.org/wordpress/whats-going-on-2/ displayed insecure content from http://abim3.improvementskills.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/run_chart2.png.
 www.improvementskills.org/wordpress/whats-going-on-2/:1"

I'm guessing this is because the image urls have http rather https.  Whenever I upload new images in wordpress it gives it http as well.  How do I go about fixing this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** The technique in my comment below is now an anti-pattern! Always use https. http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/

---

If you can edit your website's `img` tags, then remove "http:" from the `src`.

Bad
http://abim3.improvementskills.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/run_chart2.png
Good
//abim3.improvementskills.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/run_chart2.png

This way, the browser will call the image with https when needed, and http otherwise.